# vue-route How to create routes programmaticaly?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a folder that contains several page components, like:

```
 - pages
     + page-A
        + page-a.vue
     + page-B
        + page-b.vue
```

As far as I understand, if we want to render `page-a.vue` and `page-b.vue` as its own page, we must use `vue-router` which is described by:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import PageA from '@/pages/page-A/page-a';
import PageB from '@/pages/page-B/page-b';
// ... more import for each page here ....

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({

routes: [
    {
      path: '/page-a',
      name: 'PageA',
      component: PageA,
    },
    {
      path: '/page-b',
      name: 'PageB',
      component: PageB,
    },
    // ....
  ],
});
```

I had to write import for each page that I have, and also adding it to the routes, which I find as a tedious job.

Is it possible to rewrite that down to one route like: `/:page` which content then can be interpreted as a variable `page`. At least that's what I do in Express/Node server:

```
app.get('/:parent/:folder/:filename', function (req, res) {
    var parent      = req.params.parent;
    var folder      = req.params.folder;
    var filename    = req.params.filename;
    res.render(parent + '/' + folder + "/" + filename);
});
```

Comment: Just use `props: true` in router: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html

Comment: I read props documentation, but I think that's not what I need. Props map several urls to a single component (one .vue file). What I need is a way to map a url to several components.

Comment: So you cal load components inside main component based on prop value using dynamic component: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: @malcolm : no router involved here ? Afaik, dynamic component is a placeholder which content can be changed. It is still the same component, but with different content (template).

Comment: And you csn load component inside it based on route parameter in props.

Comment: @malcolm I'm lost,  do you have a sample here ?

Answer (score 0):

Vue does accept and handle routes which can contain parameters.

Your question is about **async components loading** [check here for more](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components)

And it's possible check this github issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/215